# Haskell delete Chars from String

Tags: string, haskell, char

I'm trying to write a function of the form

```
f :: String -> [String]
f str = ...
```

that returns the list of all the strings formed by removing exactly one character from `str`. For example:

```
ghci> f "stack"
["tack","sack","stck","stak","stac"]
```

Because `String` and `[Char]` are synonymous, I could use the index, but I know that you should avoid doing that in Haskell. Is there a better way besides using the index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use recursion like so:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f (s:ss) = ss : map (s:) (f ss)
```

Comment: [Right](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26936774/3); sorry about that. However, isn't it good practice to make the base case and the general case return values of the same type? Could your answer be modified accordingly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They are of the same type; it wouldn't compile otherwise. In general ``[] :: [b]`` and in this case ``b ~ [a]``.

Comment: In the base, you return the empty list, whereas, in the general case, you return a list of lists. Those are different types.

Comment: Jubobs: the empty list is also the empty list of lists :)

Comment: @rampion `[[]] == [] -> False`

Comment: There you go. Admittedly the notation can mean it's an easy mistake to make, and I've done it before.

Comment: Jubobs: Yes, the empty list is not the same as the list containing the empty list. But they're both of the same type (otherwise you couldn't compare them for equality).

Comment: @rampion Alright. I get it now. I just learned something `:)`

Comment: Consider what would happen if `f [] = [[]]`. Then `f "a" = f ('a':[]) = [] : map ('a':) (f []) = [] : map ('a':) ([[]]) = [] :  ['a':[]] = [] : ["a"] = [ [], "a" ]`

Answer (score 0):

The **Josh Kirklin**'s solution as a one-liner:

```
f = tail . foldr (\x ~(r:rs) -> (x : r) : r : map (x :) rs) [[]]
```

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn, no. This version is more readable: `f = snd . foldr (\x ~(r, rs) -> (x : r, r : map (x :) rs)) ([], [])`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more readable way to describe it is:

```
gaps :: [a] -> [[a]]
gaps xs = zipWith removeAt [0..] $ replicate (length xs) xs

removeAt i xs = ys ++ zs
    where
        (ys,_:zs) = splitAt i xs
```

But practically, it is slower than the other solutions.