# How can I get the list of strings obtained by deleting one character from a given string?

Tags: string, haskell, character

Giving a string I want to create a list of strings in which I have all the strings formed after deleting one character from the initial string. Ex mama -> [ama, mma, maa, mam].

I tried this :

```
delete1 :: String -> [String]
delete1 xs = [delete c (c:xs) |c <- xs]
```

but it does not change anything. How can I do this ?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936655/haskell-delete-chars-from-string)

Comment: @user5402 Duplicate even. Must be some homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
delete :: String -> [String]
delete [] = []
delete (x:xs) = xs : map (x:) (deleted1 xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing would (almost) work, but you are re-adding the value....

You do realize that

```
delete x (x:theList)
```

is just

```
theList
```

don't you?

Basically, `(x:theList)` tells the computer to prepend `x` to theList, while `delete x` tells the computer to remove the first `x` from the list.

This almost would work

```
[delete c xs |c <- xs]
```

but do keep in mind that delete only removes the first occurrence of the char, so you can never remove the second 'm' from mama (ie- using delete you can not get "maa")

@user5402 has shown another question with a better solution, which I won't repeat here.